# OpenApi - Not working Azure Ad Client Credentials

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, swagger, openapi

I tried logging in openapi using client credentials flow. And I can't do it. OpenApi returns me this error. I tried it in swagger as well and the result is the same. I have no idea what to do about it and I can't find much to do about it.

Thanks in advance for your help[image]

Comment: The error "Failed to fetch" is mostly related to CORS issue. Check similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70363425/configure-openapi-swagger-to-get-access-token-from-azure-ad-with-client-credenti). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337781/client-credentials-authorization-with-azure-active-directory-and-swagger) you cannot use client credentials flow for frontend. Did it work when you used delegated flows like implicit flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one Azure AD application and exposed an API with **scope** as below:

[image]

When I tried to authorize using client credentials flow, I too got **same error** with CORS issue for token endpoint in browser console as below:

[image]

> As suggested by *@juunas* in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337781/client-credentials-authorization-with-azure-active-directory-and-swagger), you cannot use client credentials flow from front-end as Azure AD **blocks** cross origin requests to its **token endpoint**.

To **resolve** the error, you need to switch to **delegated** authentication flows like implicit flow or authorization code flow that involves user interaction.

In my case, I used **implicit flow** by enabling below options in my Azure AD application:

[image]

Now, I modified the code by replacing client credentials with **implicit flow** related parameters like this:

```cs
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
    {
        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
        {
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
            TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "api://appId/ReadAccess", "" }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

[image]

When I clicked on **Authorize** option, it asked me to pick one Azure AD account and displayed below screen after **successful** authentication:

[image]

I got **response** successfully when I called the API request like this:

```
GET https://localhost:xxxx/WeatherForecast
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Enable OAuth 2 Authorization Using Azure AD And Swagger In .Net  by **Jay Krishna Reddy**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-oauth-2-authorization-using-azure-ad-and-swagger-in-net-5-0/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. The problem here is that the login is not by client_id/client_secret, but by standard username/password. I guess I don't mind, but it is a bit confusing then that the customer will use my api by calling some api of mine, where he sends client_id and client_secret and gets the access_token. But in swagger it will be authenticated via AD isn't that confusing? If that's how it's normally done, then fine and it works for me.

Comment: @SPT It helped, but it didn't solve my problem. Should I still accept it?